# How can I create this exact 5x5 matrix using only for loops?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
```

So I was given this matrix and was told to create it using only for loops. What i have done so far is using `cbind(0:4,1+(0:4),2+(0:4),3+(0:4),4+(0:4))` but i cant figure out a way to do so with the for function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track. If you rewrite your current

```
cbind(0:4,1+(0:4),2+(0:4),3+(0:4),4+(0:4))
```

as

```
cbind(0+(0:4),1+(0:4),2+(0:4),3+(0:4),4+(0:4))
```

you might notice that the thing that you are adding to `0:4` is implicitly a loop index.

Make it explicit:

```
m = c()
for(i in 0:4){
  m = cbind(m,i+(0:4))
} 
print(m)
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    2    3    4
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]    2    3    4    5    6
[4,]    3    4    5    6    7
[5,]    4    5    6    7    8
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your  answers, they have been super helpful! I was wondering how to create this exact matrix above, this time without using for loops, but with the exclusive use of matrix operations. Thanks again in advance for everyone taking the time to answer

Comment: @mxalbeta for loops are *not* the way that one would normally construct a matrix like this, but how to do so without loops is literally a different question. Perhaps you can accept one of the answers here (which ever one helped you the most) and then ask a brand new question.

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
mat <- matrix(0L, nrow=5, ncol=5) 
for (i in 0:4) {
  for (j in 0:4) {
    mat[i + 1, j + 1] <- i + j
  }
}
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    1    2    3    4
# [2,]    1    2    3    4    5
# [3,]    2    3    4    5    6
# [4,]    3    4    5    6    7
# [5,]    4    5    6    7    8
```

And technically *apply functions are loops as well:

```
sapply(0:4, \(x) 0:4 + x)
```

Comment: `sapply(0:4, \(x) 0:4 + x)` is really the most elegant of solutions, even if it may not meet the (i assume) homework requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can just create an empty matrix first and then fill it with two for-loops iterating over rows and columns. Playing a little bit around with the variable to write into the matrix (`count`) I figured out that this is a suitable solution.

```
matrix2fill <- matrix(NA, 5,5)
count = 0
for (i in 1:5){
  for (j in 1:5){
    matrix2fill[j,i] = count
    count = count + 1
  }
  count = i
}

matrix2fill
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    2    3    4
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]    2    3    4    5    6
[4,]    3    4    5    6    7
[5,]    4    5    6    7    8
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

```
mymat <- matrix(NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
i_mat <- 1
for (i in 0:4) {
  mymat[seq(i_mat, i_mat + 4)] <- seq(i, i + 4)
  i_mat <- i_mat + 5
}
mymat

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    2    3    4
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]    2    3    4    5    6
[4,]    3    4    5    6    7
[5,]    4    5    6    7    8
```

Comment: "Yet another way" -- a good description of R. There is almost always multiple ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = matrix(1:25, nrow=5, ncol=5) 
for (i in 1:5) {
   for (j in 1:5) {
      a[i][j] = (i-1) + (j-1)
   }
}
print(a)
```